# URL Rewriting affects the data from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, iis, url-rewriting

I need a help on URL Rewrite for my HTML5 application, Which is hosted on IIS.

In my app, I have page for list the schools. The school data(JSON) is from C# ASP.net API. I'm getting the data by using AngularJS($http.Get).

The school page is working fine when i am running alone i.e without Angular Routing. After I included Angular JS Routing and host in my Local IIS, All pages working pretty good except the Schools page, this is the only page i'm getting data from API,

My API URL:

```
http://localhost/ita_calender_api/ita/values
```

school page url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Schools
```

(note: My app is running in 8080 port and api is in default)

URL Rewrite in Web.config:

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}"  pattern="ITA_CALENDER_API/(.*)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
```

When i load this url in browser i'm getting the schools page as a XHR response with the status of 500

[image]

One thing i did forgot to include:
The CORS access for my schools page alone:

```
<location path="web/Schools.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost/" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: Are you using ASP Web API or MVC? Do you have a `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs` or `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` where you could manage your routes?

Comment: I'm using `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` to config routes...

Comment: Are you using both `MVC` and `Web API` in separate projects? Your API url doesn't have a port number: `http://localhost/ita_calender_api/ita/values`. Is this a mistake? If you are using `WebApiConfig.cs`, then you are not using `ASP MVC` but `ASP Web Api`, which is different. You cannot serve `HTML` files directly from `Web API`.

Comment: @cl3m My MVC api service running in my localhost's default port and my HTML5 application running in localhost's 8080 port.

Comment: But its worked when running schools page separately  i.e) without  routing

Comment: Are you running both projects at the same time? I don't understand what is your problem exactly: You cannot access your api from Angular from you school.html page, or, you cannot access your school.html page at all ?

Comment: The routes in your webconfig seems to configure Api routes (`ITA_CALENDER_API/*`). Whereas your `500` error comes from the `School.html` route. I don't really get your issue there :S

Comment: simply say... My page works perfectly when `http://localhost:8080/web/schools.html` but not works in `http://localhost:8080/Schools` @cl3m I can acces the page but data from API won't come when i include routing

Comment: So, is what you need just a redirect from `/Scools` to `/web/schools.html` ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
If you are just looking to redirect from `/School` to `/web/schools.html` you could just do hte following:

```
    [Route("~/School")]
    public ActionResult YourActionThatReturnsSchoolDotHtml()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Alternatively, you could do a simple `RedirectToAction`:

```
    public ActionResult YourActionThatReturnsSchoolDotHtml()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("~/School")]
    public ActionResult Schools()
    {
        return RedirectToRoute(YourActionThatReturnsSchoolDotHtml());
    }
```

I'm not sure if this will help you, but if you are using `ASP MVC`, you could setup your routes via the App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file like this:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Schools",
    url: "Schools/{*url}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Schools", action = "Index" }
);
```

And then, in your `SchoolsController.cs`:

```
[Route("Schools/{*url}")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Provided you also have an `index.cshtml` file under `Views/Schools` directory

This will basically redirect every calls to `/Schools/*` MVC action to your `angular router`

Comment: First of all I didn't return views from my api. It returns only the JSON data.. which is shown in the Schools page

Comment: Normally, Web API returns JSON, your ASP MVC returns views

Comment: I think i confused you... My api only returns JSON data... since I'm a beginner, I can't explain you well

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry, i'm confused. Where does your `/web/school.html` come from?

Comment: When i click schools on navbar it route by `.when('/Schools', {
            templateUrl: 'web/Schools.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })` this is in angular route configure...

Comment: Yes, but this `web/Schools.html` comes from somewhere. It has to be send by your server to Angular. You should create an action in your Web API server that will send your `School.html` file. Take a look at this : http://forums.asp.net/t/1785552.aspx?Hosting+static+content+in+a+self+hosted+webapi